# Validate a formControl in angular reactive from which contains "@gmail.com"

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have created one userInfo form and i want to validate email field like it should contain @gmail.com, I want only gmail users , I have used reactive forms and i want the emailAddress field to be validated.

Here is my user job form

```
<div>
  <form  [formGroup]="jobform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="emailAddress" class="form-control"  />                

    <button [disabled]="!jobform.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Component.ts :

```
export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {
    userFormGroup: FormGroup  

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }   

    ngOnInit() {
        this.jobform= this.fb.group({
            emailAddress:['', Validators.required],
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, what I have tried which I have explained with code. I know custom validator but how to validate gmail I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a regex check in the form control which checks your requirement.
An apt regex for your requirement could be `/^.+@gmail.com$/`

You can add the validator as:

```
this.jobform= this.fb.group({
     emailAddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^.+@gmail.com$')]]
});
```

Comment: @AmiVyas: Please check the updated answer, I have added a validator which checks correct email(without invalid characters). I have also replace the `*` with a `+` in the regex.